# SAS Transpose and Reshape Dataset

Tags: sas

I have the original dataset in the following structure:

```
| Ticker   | Time     | Stock Return |
|----------|----------|--------------|
| Facebook | 12:00:01 | 1%           |
| Facebook | 12:00:02 | 1.5%         |
| ...      |          |              |
| Apple    | 12:00:01 | -0.5%        |
| Apple    | 12:00:02 | -0.3%        |
| ...      |          |              |
| Alibaba  | 12:00:01 | -0.5%        |
| Alibaba  | 12:00:02 | -0.3%        |
| ...      |          |              |
```

Now, I want to construct a new dataset with the following structure:

```
| Facebook | Apple |   ...... | Alibaba |
|----------|-------|----------|---------|
| 1%       | 1.3%  |          | 1.8%    |
| 1.5%     | 1.2%  |          | 1.5%    |
| ...      | ...   |          | ...     |
| 0.1%     | 1.7%  |          | 1.3%    |
| 0.3%     | 2.3%  |          | 0.2%    |
```

That is, I dropped all the variables but the stock return. The stock return variable in the new dataset is renamed as the stock ticker names.

The time should be continuous (second-by-second) and they are supposed to match in each row.

In the original dataset, there might be duplicate stock tickers in different rows.

I was wondering how can I accomplish this? I am doing this for a Principle Component Analysis.

I am thinking about the following way:

```
DATA PCASET; 
    SET ORIGINAL DATASET; 

RUN;
```

However, I don't know how to name the columns ...

Comment: PROC TRANSPOSE after you've compiled the data to make sense. How are you planning to deal with those multiple records?

Comment: I plan to run a proc factor on it. It's like this: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_factor_sect028.htm

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to your question at all.

Comment: I need to prepare the data for a principle component analysis.

Comment: Still not relevant to your question - one question at a time. Your current question is how do I reformat my data. Or is it something else? I would have assumed you would have already checked with proc factor/pca that this is the type of format you need, because I won't do that for you.

Comment: I checked. This is the format I need.

Comment: Will a simple transpose work? Because there are multiple rows with the same stock names and a transpose would produce duplicate columns ...

Comment: What happens when you tried the Transpose? You lose nothing by trying it out first....

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-long-to-wide-using-proc-transpose/

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-long-to-wide-using-the-data-step/

Comment: @Reeza Please see my updated post.

Comment: If you run into issues like this, the fastest way to see what happens is to test it. You should read up on PROC TRANSPOSE, search some papers on LexJansen.com - it has tutorials for anything you're possibly interested in regarding SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the TIME variable then you need to sort by TIME and TICKER and then transpose.

```
 proc sort data=have;
   by time ticker ;
 run;
 proc transpose data=have out=want ;
   by time ;
   id ticker ;
   var stock_return ;
 run;
```

You will then get one observation per time value.

Otherwise you need to reduce the data to one record per TICKER and then use the same transpose without the BY statement so that you get a single output observation.

Comment: I am getting very weird results after the transpose. There are some columns with data missing, and some columns (the last ones) without tickers. Why is that?

Comment: @JinhuaWang is your log error free? Usually this means you haven't processed your input data set correctly. As Tom stated, you need to reduce the data to one record per ticker per second. If any data is missing a ticker before it will after transpose.

Comment: The log is error free up to the transpose step. I was thinking is it because not every stock is included in every time slot? Some stock doesn't always trade... but this should cause empty column names and non-empty column content either.

Comment: @JinhuaWang the statement 'this should cause empty column names' doesn't make sense. Think about how a transpose should work - you're flipping data and expect a record for each time/ticker. If there's no ticker then there's no column heading but if you even have one record for a ticker symbol you'll get a column.  I think you need to read the manual and some documentation here. Or play around to see what you get with a small test data set so you understand it. I recommend the latter personally.

Comment: @Reeza I tried the UCLA example and they seem to work. I also played around with it, deleting some ids and i did find that the column names are still there, but only with some void column contents. Now I am even more unsure of what happened on my stock dataset ... It seems that there is no reason to have void coumn names, but i have the last 100 something columns without a name ....

Comment: Check your input data. Is it missing any values in the TICKER list? Is there any error for your PROC TRANSPOSE? You said it was ok up to it, not beyond it.